# Get the parameters of a JavaScript function with Scrapy

Tags: javascript, python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

I was wondering if it is possible to extract the parameters of a JavaScript function with Scrapy, from a code similar to this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
  function initialize() {
    var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(43.2640611,2.9388228);
  };
}
</script>
```

I would like to extract the coordinates `43.2640611` and `2.9388228`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'extract'. You can define `var lat=43.26, lng=2.93` and than pass it to the method?

Comment: @AamirAfridi The OP means - extract using Scrapy, the Python crawler engine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is where [`re()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.re) method would help.

The idea is to locate the `script` tag via `xpath()` and use `re()` to extract the `lat` and `lng` from the `script` tag's contents. Demo from the [`scrapy shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
$ scrapy shell index.html
>>> response.xpath('//script').re(r'new google\.maps\.LatLng\(([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+)\);')
[u'43.2640611', u'2.9388228']
```

where `index.html` contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
  function initialize() {
    var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(43.2640611,2.9388228);
  };
}
</script>
```

<sub>Of course, in your case the xpath would not be just `//script`.</sub>

FYI, `new google\.maps\.LatLng\(([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+)\);` regular expression uses the [saving groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `([0-9.]+)` to extract the coordinate values.

Also see [Using selectors with regular expressions](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this approach, but here's how I would think about it if I was constrained to using Scrapy and didn't want to parse JavaScript the way alecxe suggested above. This is a finicky, fragile hack :-)

You can try using [scrapyjs](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs) to execute the JavaScript code from your scrapy crawler. In order to capture those parameters, you'd need to do the following:

1. Load the original page and save it to disk.
2. Modify the page to replace google.maps.LatLng function with your own (see below). make sure to run your script AFTER google js is loaded.
3. Load the modified page using scrapyjs (or the instance of webkit created by it)
4. Parse the page, look for the two special divs created by your fake LatLng function that contain the extracted lat and lng variables.

More on step 2: Make your fake LatLng function modify the HTML page to expose lat and lng variables so that you could parse them out with Scrapy. Here is some crude code to illustrate:

```
var LatLng = function LatLng(lat, lng) {
  var latDiv = document.createElement("div");
  latDiv.id = "extractedLat";
  latDiv.innerHtml = lat;
  document.body.appendChild(latDiv);

  var lngDiv = document.createElement("div");
  lngDiv.id = "extractedLng";
  lngDiv.innerHtml = lng;
  document.body.appendChild(lngDiv);
}

google = {
  map: {
    LatLng: LatLng
  }
};
```

Overall, this approach sounds a bit painful, but could be fun to try.